# Erorrs in console log after renaming a endpoint

Tags: sveltekit

i **had** a endpoint in /api/dc but renamed it to /api/dw. I changed all the references to /api/dc to /api/dw.
The code works as it should. But every 5 minutes or so i get this error in the console:

```
Error: Not found: /api/dc
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:395:13)
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:236:5)
    at Object.#options.hooks.handle (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:41:55)
    at Module.respond (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:233:40)
```

In Visual Studio i checked if there are any occurences of /api/dc, there aren't any. I deleted .sveltekit directory, updated sveltekit and reinstalled sveltekit completely. I restarted dev-server several times.

Somehow there must be some cache, i cannot find.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an old version of the site loaded in a different browser tab?

Comment: no, i also have closed all browsers and openened an incognito tab.

Comment: you might want to nuke your `node_modules` directory and run a clean install of all ur modules, bc the stack trace just look like it's trying to ping that api and was somehow cached in the node_modules